# Installing Linux

Tags: linux, kernel

I have downloaded Kernel 3.3.4 for Linux. I need to actually get the OS. What is the most current version of Linux that uses this kernel and where can I get it from?

Comment: 2 things: (1) this is a programming Q&A site, this is off-topic. (2) Linux really is just a kernel. There are dozens of OSs that *use* this kernel, like Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, Rehat, Suse, Gentoo, etc.

Comment: @Chris I am sorry about posting this on the wrong site I didn't do this on purpose. Is the rep deduction necessary?

Comment: There was no rep deduction from me. And since it's been migrated to another site, any votes on SO are no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

What you downloaded is only part of a fully operational operating system. The kernel performs functions necessary to the OS, but is not entire OS by itself.  What you should really be looking for is a GNU/Linux distribution. These contain the a bundled kernel with the rest of the files needed. From experience Ubuntu and Fedora use very recent kernel versions.  Fedora is your best bet for a kernel that recent, but Ubuntu is more stable, even though it might not be that exact kernel.

GNU -- The majority of the rest of the OS

Linux -- The kernel

This is the reason they are sometimes and appropriately called GNU/Linux Distributions. A while back they decided to combine the Linux Kernel, with the incomplete GNU operating system.

http://fedoraproject.org/

http://www.ubuntu.com/

Both of these come with live cds. These you burn and then boot off of. You might have to change some BIOS settings so that you can boot off a cd. Then you follow the steps detailed for the site you use. I recommend if this is your first installation of Linux to use Ubuntu.

**NOTE: The kernel comes with the distribution there is no need to download it before hand.**

Answer (score 0):

What Linux are you running? ubuntu, arch etc. If you download a linux distro they all come with the necessary kernel needed. The Linux OS's have some great wiki's its worth having a good read on them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly download your preferred Linux OS directly? You have every single Linux OS available to download. Just check out Wikipedia for it. That's a real good source for Linux. I also recommend linuxdistros.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to download packages (i.e desktop environment) now, but things you are doning are not for people new to linux.